# X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 9, the number of features at training time

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, svm, shapes

I'm trying to plot my Binary SVM classifier results using `matplotlib.pyplot` and using this documentation as a guide:

https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html

Here's my code:

```
# create a mesh to plot in
h = .02
x_min, x_max = X.min() - 1, X.max() + 1
y_min, y_max = 0,1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))


# PLOT
for i, clf in enumerate((svc, lin_svc, rbf_svc, poly_svc)):
    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.4)

    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)

    # Plot also the training points
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.xticks(())
    plt.yticks(())
    plt.title(titles[i])

plt.show()
```

Where X.shape = (10769, 9), and the class values are either 0 or 1, hence why I set y_min and y_max to 0 and 1.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 9, the number of features at training time
```

I'm not sure if I understand how to plot SVMs correctly - what am I doing wrong?

Here is the link to the notebook with the full code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F3_CFIDv8qaDeWodujpeu4phQADFpodP?usp=sharing 
Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Kindly post the entire traceback

Comment: Here is the link to the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F3_CFIDv8qaDeWodujpeu4phQADFpodP?usp=sharing